# button stopped making POST request

Tags: php, http

I am facing a strange issue here,I had a piece of code which was working fine until yesterday.Suddenly my button has stopped making POST Request.
Below is the sample code.When i click on the button `btnsubmit` ,the page gets redirected to view_teacherupdate.php but it doesnt print "button submitted";

```
<form  method="post" action="view_teacherUpdate.php">
  <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

view_teacherUpdate.php

```
if(isset($_POST["btnsubmit"]))
{
  echo "button submitted";
}
```

I have enabled `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but I am not getting any error or warning.

Session is enabled in both pages.

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Full Code:

ViewTeacherUpdatePage:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
//require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('includewisdom/login.php');
}
function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
    switch ($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["btnUpdateNew"]))
{
    echo "hfvghfhgfhgf enter";
    $TeacherID=5;
    $teachername=trim($_POST["teachername"]);
    $current_address=trim($_POST["current_address"]);
    $teaching_locationsarray=$_POST["teaching_locations"];
    $teaching_locationsarray=array_unique($teaching_locationsarray);
    $teaching_location="";
        foreach($teaching_locationsarray as $temp)
        {
        $teaching_location=$temp.",".$teaching_location;
        }
    $teaching_location=rtrim($teaching_location,",");
        //echo $teaching_location;
    $teachingzone=trim($_POST["teachingzone"]);
    //$TeacherLocation[]
    $TeacherLocationarray=$_POST["TeacherLocation"];
    $TeacherLocationarray=array_unique($TeacherLocationarray);
    $TeacherLocation="";
        foreach($TeacherLocationarray as $temp)
        {
        $TeacherLocation=$temp.",".$TeacherLocation;
        }
    $TeacherLocation=rtrim($TeacherLocation,",");
    //$residenceZone=trim($_POST["residenceZone"]);
    //$Teaching_subject[]
    $Teaching_subjectarray=$_POST["Teaching_subject"];
    $Teaching_subjectarray=array_unique($Teaching_subjectarray);
    $Teaching_subject="";
        foreach($Teaching_subjectarray as $temp)
        {
        $Teaching_subject=$temp.",".$Teaching_subject;
        }
    $Teaching_subject=rtrim($Teaching_subject,",");
    //$residenceZone=trim($_POST["residenceZone"]);
    //$TeachingGroup[]
    $TeachingGrouparray=$_POST["TeachingGroup"];
    $TeachingGrouparray=array_unique($TeachingGrouparray);
    $TeachingGroup="";
        foreach($TeachingGrouparray as $temp)
        {
        $TeachingGroup=$temp.",".$TeachingGroup;
        }
    $TeachingGroup=rtrim($TeachingGroup,",");
    //$residenceZone=trim($_POST["residenceZone"]);
    //$edu_subject[]
    $edu_subjectarray=$_POST["edu_subject"];
    $edu_subjectarray=array_unique($edu_subjectarray);
    $edu_subject="";
        foreach($edu_subjectarray as $temp)
        {
        $edu_subject=$temp.",".$edu_subject;
        }
    $edu_subject=rtrim($edu_subject,",");
    //$residenceZone=trim($_POST["residenceZone"]);
    //$EducationGroup[]
    $EducationGrouparray=$_POST["EducationGroup"];
    $EducationGrouparray=array_unique($EducationGrouparray);
    $EducationGroup="";
        foreach($EducationGrouparray as $temp)
        {
        $EducationGroup=$temp.",".$EducationGroup;
        }
    $EducationGroup=rtrim($EducationGroup,",");
    $residenceZone=trim($_POST["residenceZone"]);
    $gender=trim($_POST["gender"]);
    $board=trim($_POST["board"]);
    $Qualification=trim($_POST["Qualification"]);
    $enrollmentdate=trim($_POST["enrollmentdate"]);
    $dob=trim($_POST["dob"]);
}
```

ViewTeacherPage(where button gets clicked)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
//require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('PAC_PATH','phpAutocomplete');
require_once("phpAutocomplete/conf.php");
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('includewisdom/login.php');
}
$tutorRequirement=[];

if(isset($_POST["deleteDocs"]))
{
    $TeacherID=trim($_GET["id"]);
    //echo $TeacherID;
    $stmt1 = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE `teacher_info` SET `idproof`='',`degree`='',`marksheet`='',`tenmarksheet`='',`degreemarksheet`='',
    `additionalDocuments`='',
`addressproof`='' WHERE userid=:uid");
            $stmt1->bindparam(":uid",$TeacherID);
            $stmt1->execute();  
    //echo "sgadjfdgs";
}



if(isset($_POST["submitRequestRequirement"]))
{
    $noteid=trim($_GET["noteid"]);
    $tutorid=trim($_GET["id"]);
    $stmtInsert="";
    $stmtRequest = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `TutorRequestRequirement` WHERE TutorID='$tutorid' and RequestID='$noteid'");
    $stmtRequest->execute();
    //fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    $tutorRequirement = $stmtRequest->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $requestRequirement=trim($_POST["requestRequirement"]);
    if(count($tutorRequirement)>0)
    {
        $stmtInsert = $user_home->runQuery("Update TutorRequestRequirement set Requirement=:Requirement where TutorID=:TutorID and RequestID=:RequestID");
    }
    else
    {
    $stmtInsert = $user_home->runQuery("INSERT INTO `TutorRequestRequirement`(`TutorID`, `Requirement`, `RequestID`) Values
            (:TutorID,:Requirement,:RequestID)");   
    }

            $stmtInsert->bindparam(":TutorID",$tutorid);
            $stmtInsert->bindparam(":Requirement",$requestRequirement);
            $stmtInsert->bindparam(":RequestID",$noteid);
            $result=$stmtInsert->execute();

}
if(isset($_GET["noteid"]))
{
    $noteid=trim($_GET["noteid"]);
    $tutorid=trim($_GET["id"]);
    $stmtRequest = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `TutorRequestRequirement` WHERE TutorID='$tutorid' and RequestID='$noteid'");
    $stmtRequest->execute();
    //fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    $tutorRequirement = $stmtRequest->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //echo count($tutorRequirement);
    //var_dump($tutorRequirement);
}

function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
    switch ($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}


$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM RoleInfoWisdomManagementSystem WHERE id=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$msg = "<div class='alert alert-block' style='background:#48cfad;margin-top:10px'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                        <strong>  Your Profile Updated Successfully. </strong>
                        </div>";
$role=$row['role'];
$name=$row['Name'];

$TeacherID=trim($_GET["id"]);
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM teacher_info WHERE userid=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$TeacherID));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$teachingPreferencearray=explode(",",$row["tution_type"]);

$stmtArea = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM kolkata_locations");
$stmtArea->execute();
$rowarea = $stmtArea->fetchAll();

$stmt112 = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT distinct `subject_name` FROM `subjects`");
$stmt112->execute();
$rowsubjects = $stmt112->fetchAll();

$stmt1123 = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `subjects`");
$stmt1123->execute();
$rowTeachingsubjects = $stmt1123->fetchAll();
//$arrinbox=explode("#",$inbox);

<form  method="post" action="view_teacherUpdate.php">
<button id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdateNew" value="btnUpdateNew"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>

      </form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129122/discussion-on-question-by-r-r-button-stopped-making-post-request).

Comment: try debugging with `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see exactly what you recieve on that page

Comment: First things first. I think you didn't paste the exact code in page ViewTeacherPag because php tag isn't closed before line 121 and is giving the error: Unexpected < on line 121

Comment: Why two submit buttons in the same form? 
You have an input of type submit without a pre-defined text label ( value="Text label of the button" ) and a button of type submit called "Save".
When I click the input of type submit I don't send the variable "btnUpdateNew" because this submit input has no name.
When I click the Save button I send the variable "btnUpdateNew" because this name is defined in this button, so because of it the fragment bellow is reached:
    if(isset($_POST["btnUpdateNew"]))
    {
        echo "hfvghfhgfhgf enter";
    ...

Comment: As I mentioned earlier it was a working code.i have closed the php tags :) and the 2 button i was using to debug the issue.

Comment: What are the actual filenames you use for your files? Because the way it is formatted now, it could be that the TARGET for your form is just wrong.

You list the files as 'ViewTeacherUpdatePage' and 'ViewTeacherPage', your forms has as target 'view_teacherUpdate.php'.

Also, does clicking the button do anything at all? Does it redirect? Does it change the page? Or does it simply not print what you expected it to print?

Comment: It redirects to the page which is mentioned in the action attribute of the form but doesn't recognize the btn submitted

Comment: try adding www.yourdomain.com if you are using directly "yourdomain.com", it could be some server redirection issue.
or you can try if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'] && (!empty($_POST['btnsubmit']))))..
I hope your issue would get resolved

Comment: @RR What browser do you use? Can you check the "Network" tab in the browsers devtools to see HOW the request is done to view_teacherUpdate.php. Be sure to check the 'Keep requests' checkbox so the log isn't wiped every page-load.

That tab should also tell you what data was posted to the server, which then hydrates the $_POST variable.

Answer (score 4):

The code you submitted contains 2 submit-buttons (1 < button >, 1 < input type="submit" >. Depending on the button pressed, a different value is actually submitted. I guess that the form only adds the button (or element type=submit) that was actually clicked to the POST-data (which makes sense from an UI-standpoint)

Depending on the button pressed I either got

```
Array ( [btnsubmit] => Verzenden )
```

or

```
Array ( [btnUpdateNew] => btnUpdateNew )
```

("Verzenden" is the dutch translation for Send, as the browser translates this)

So, could it be that you were pressing the wrong button by any chance?

```
<form  method="post" action="view_teacherUpdate.php">
  <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit"/>
  <button id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdateNew" value="btnUpdateNew" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `ViewTeacherPage(where button gets clicked)`, you forgot to close the `<?php` tag before the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ViewTeacherPage.php` file. In this file Last three line for html Code Is correct. But you can put this code inside php tag. So, First closed php Tag. After put your html code.

```
 <form  method="post" action="view_teacherUpdate.php">
      <button id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdateNew" value="btnUpdateNew"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>

 </form>
 ?>
```

To Replace this

```
 ?>
<form  method="post" action="view_teacherUpdate.php">
  <button id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdateNew" value="btnUpdateNew"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there went something wrong with the required file `includewisdom/class.user.php`. Did you change that file recently? There can be also corrupted database tables for the user data when trying to check if the user is logged in. Check your database and the hosting log files for any errors.

**Things to do to debug this**

1. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top and then generate a division by zero warning and throw a custom error to see if PHP errors are working:

   ```
   <?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   $i = 2 / 0; // Warning: Division by zero in ...
   throw new Exception('Custom error to see if errors are working.'); // Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Custom error to see if errors are working.

   session_start();
   require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
   //require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
   //error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $user_home = new USER();
   ```

   If you see the *warning* and the *fatal error* then you can see errors and you can continue.
   Also try to throw a custom error imidiately after the `$user_home = new USER();`; maybe there is some other code inside the `class.user.php` that disables `error_reporting`.
2. Directly place the POST detection immediately after the `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

   ```
   <?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   if(isset($_POST["btnUpdateNew"]))
   {
       die("POST btnUpdateNew exists");
   }

   session_start();
   require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
   //require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
   //error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $user_home = new USER();
   ```

   If you don't see the message, the the PHP script does not execute at all and maybe there is some server user pool restrictions for the current user running the PHP script `view_teacherupdate.php` under that particular site.
   If you see the `POST btnUpdateNew exists` after you post the form, then the form is OK and the problem is somewhere at the user managment calls `new USER();` or `$user_home->is_logged_in()`. 
   Maybe there is something triggering an `exit`. To check this, try to print something after the check and call the `$user_home->is_logged_in()` function like this:

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
   //require_once 'includewisdom/class.user.php';
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $user_home = new USER();

   if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
   {
       $user_home->redirect('includewisdom/login.php');
   }

   echo "User is logged in<br>";
   ```

   If you don't see the message, then you got the problem and it's hidding insinde the user managment class; at its code or logic or maybe some data corruption when trying to read user info from the database.

   If you see message "User is logged in" then put a post debug at the top of `view_teacherupdate.php` like this:

   ```
   <pre><?php print_r($_POST) ?></pre>
   ```

   with this, you'll find out exactly what the `$_POST` array contains when the script receives POST data.

   Then check the POST data and please update your question with the result!